# How to pass a pointer from the same structure to the structure in nasm?

Tags: assembly, struct, nasm

I'm developing a chained list in nasm but I'm facing a problem. How can I do to add a pointer of the structure in the same structure for the case of the following and previous pointers I will show you what I would like to do in C and I would like to do it in assembler.

```
BITS 64

segment .bss
    struc list 
        val: resd 1
        next: resq 1  
        back: resq 1  
    endstruc

segment .text
```

And here is what I would like to do in a nutshell

```c
struct liste {
    int donnee;
    struct liste * precedent;
    struct liste * suivant;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly code you have provided is already defining the same struct members as the C struct - in assembly language there is effectively no typing. So when you do `next: resq 1`, you are defining an 8-byte space with label `next` into which you can store a pointer.

Note that while the structs have the same members, they will not be ABI-compatible, meaning that the struct cannot be shared as-is between C and ASM code. This is due to the differing alignments of the members within the structs - since `val` is only a 4-byte value, in the ASM struct `next` will be misaligned and start at byte 4 of the struct, whereas in the C version, it would be aligned to an 8-byte boundary and thus start at byte 8 of the struct.

To fix the mismatch between C and ASM, you could either:

1. Make the C version tightly packed as well, by specifying `__attribute__((packed))` in the struct definition
2. Specify `align 8` before the `resq` in the ASM struct definition, to align the pointers to the 8-byte boundary

Comment: The C isn't use `__attribute__((packed))`, and the asm isn't using `align 8` before the `dq`, so they're actually not equivalent.  Otherwise yes, they're close.

Comment: Great point Peter! I have edited the answer to avoid incorrectly stating that they are equivalent.

Comment: I'd suggest actually pointing out (in a 2nd paragraph) that they're not ABI-compatible, so C functions that want to pass or return that struct to an asm function would have a problem.  "The same struct members" isn't technically wrong, but it could easily be misread by people that don't notice the difference between that and "the same struct", not thinking about the fact that asm doesn't implicitly enforce ABI rules the way C does.

Comment: Nice edit.  A final option would be to put the pointers first, before the data, so the padding (to make the size a multiple of the alignment) would be after the last member.

Comment: A NASM structure definition should use `align 8, resb 1` or `alignb 8` to avoid a warning.

Comment: Thanks you very much